# paging and sorting using jquery

Tags: jquery, pagination

How can i see paging usng jquery,also should have facility to see amount of records selected from drop down.For eg Dropdown conains 10,20,30,40,if i want to see 40 records then i would select 40,by default it will show 10 records perpage,Secondly i also want to use paging and searching techniques.Please help.

Comment: This question is missing some important information. Are you using PHP, ASP.NET? What data is being paginated? Is it in a database? Is it already on the page, you just want to show portions at a time?

Comment: Same exact question you asked 6 hours ago.  Although, with a little more (and a little less) detail.  You should edit your previous question to add this detail rather than create a new one.

Comment: And from your gravatar, it appears that you have at least 6 different accounts.  You might want to ask a moderator (contact team@stackoverflow.com) to help you get these coalesced into a single account.

Answer (score 1):

[Here](http://d-scribe.de/webtools/jquery-pagination/demo/demo_options.htm) You can paginate with jQuery, You can also set the number of results

For professional projects, especially for searching purpose it is better to use server side languages like PHP, Ror or similar